# Ruby Memory Growing, Looks like its keeping call stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm using Delayed for Ruby on Rails and I have ~100k jobs that I need run. These jobs are filling my local database with test data. I start the worker from the Rails console and it starts running through my jobs at a pretty quick rate (5 to 10 jobs per second). After a minute or two, it noticeably slows down (1 job per 2 seconds). I dug into ObjectSpace to see what was growing and I found that strings were steadily growing into the low millions. I pulled some of them off and they are like the following:

```
"/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@company/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:259:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'"
```

In ObjectSpace, this particular one appeared 16,197 times. It looks like a backtrace from an exception, although everything seems to be caught and handled. There are no crashes in the rails console, and the worker hums happily along. There are a number of other backtrace strings like this one.

My question is, is it possible to suppress the collection of backtrace information? Possibly via a configuration setting somewhere? My versions are as follows.

```
Rails 3.2.18
ruby 2.1.7p400
delayed_job 3.0.5
```